# Using Compound Assignment Operators When Passed Eigen Vector As A Pointer

Tags: c++, eigen

If I pass say an Eigen Vector3 as a pointer to a method, then in the method I want to add information stored in a local Vector3 to it using compound assignment operator.

e.g.

```
  void method_rest(Eigen::Vector3* test_vector) {

       Eigen::Vector3 addition_test_vector(1.0,2.0,3.0) ;

       test_vector += addition_test_vector;
       // Obviously not valid, but can this be done without having to do
       // for (int i = 0 ; i < 3 ; i++) 
       //    test_vector->coeff(i) += addition_test_vector(i) ;

    }
```

Comment: What about (*test_vector) += addition_test_vector;? Or i missed something?

Comment: You should rather pass it by reference, unless `test_vector==nullptr` is valid.

Comment: Thanks Dark_Davier, I was just being dumb.